# phantomjs page.sendEvent not working

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm scraping Instagram which is built with React, so i'm trying to comment on a post which will be only posted by pressing the enter key in the textarea. Which will trigger the onkeypress event of React. i have tried to trigger the keypress event with page.sendEvent but it doesn't do anything.

```
                    page.evaluate(function(mimicKeyPress, _$) {
                        mimicKeyPress(_$("._bilrf"), "my Comment")
                    },mimicKeyPress, _$)

                    page.sendEvent("keypress", page.event.key.ENTER)

                    setTimeout(function() {                            
                        page.render("a.jpg"); phantom.exit()
                    }, 5000)
```

Comment: What is mimickeypress? What is _$? Does React show and work correct even *before* posting comment? Are there any errors? What version is PhantomJS?

Comment: mimickeypress is my own custom function what it does is, it updates the input value of the textarea as I can't directly set its value because of React. _$ is also another custom function which returns the specified element. the version of PhantomJS is 2.1.1 and there are no errors. and yes i can see the text filled in the textarea.